# How to resolve this delegate?

Tags: c#

I was taking a technical exam to enter a company, which I've fail, and despite knowing that I was not prepared for the position.

I was wondering how to solve this exercise, since it is one of those that I honestly did not understand how to do it.

I wanted to know if someone could explain to me, I want to take advantage of the bad that happened, btw I really want to continue learning and for a next technical exam for other company and I hope I can improve it.

The code belong says you to create a program that can create a Chicken and lay some egg. But egg can be hatched by any bird, like eagle, falcon or any kind of bird.

The Exercise test says:

0- implement all this methods.
1- create one chicken lay an egg.
2- create an egg for a chiken.
3- create another bird.

```
using System;

public interface IBird
{
    Egg Lay();
}

public class Chicken
{
    public Chicken()
    {
    }
}

public class Egg
{
    public Egg(Func<IBird> createBird)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    }

    public IBird Hatch()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //      var chicken1 = new Chicken();
        //      var egg = chicken1.Lay();
        //      var childChicken = egg.Hatch();
    }
}
```

I really hope if it's anyone can help me, I am really frustrated because I'm a Software Developer, I have up to 7 years programming and I can't resolve some basics topics.

Comment: Why did you tag this php and r-exams? This is C# and completely unrelated to r-exams.

Comment: sorry i did wrong tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make this code work,

```
  var chicken1 = new Chicken();
  var egg = chicken1.Lay();
  var childChicken = egg.Hatch();
```

First, the Chicken should implement the interface from Bird:

```
public class Chicken : IBird
{
    public Chicken()
    {
    }
}
```

for that, it needs to implement the Lay() method:

```
public class Chicken : IBird
{
    public Chicken()
    {
    }

    public Egg Lay()
    {
        return new Egg(() => new Chicken());
    }

}
```

Egg expects a function that returns a new Bird. In this case, we have the constructor for Chicken. Egg needs to store a reference to it in a class member, so we use `Func<IBird>` to indicate we have a function that returns an IBird.

Then the implementation of Egg is

```cs
public class Egg
{
    Func<IBird> creator;
    public Egg(Func<IBird> createBird)
    {
        this.creator = createBird;
    }

    public IBird Hatch()
    {
        return creator();
    }
}
```